# BLDC 3phase motor. The resistor 5W 0.1 ohm to ground very hot when motor working at 250Hz

Tags: resistors, brushless-dc-motor, shunt, overheat

Any one help me on this my issuse.
I have a BLDC 3 phase motor controler similar to this Schem here encloses. When the motor working at 150Hz everything is ok. But if it is works at 250Hz then the Resistor 5W 0.1 ohm ( Red mark) very hot. Any one can tell me what happen?
Thank you.
[image]

Actually I have no detail schematic but have 2 PCB exactly same and connected whit same motor. but one of them works fine with both 150Hz and 250Hz. The rest only works normal at 150Hz. But for 250Hz the Resistor too hot. 150Hz - 220mA. 250Hz - 350mA (when motor works stable)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezhBQ.jpg)[image][image][image]

Comment: 5W resistor gets hot.  What does that tell you?

Comment: Similar circuits just ain't good enough. The devil's in the detail. What supply current at 150 Hz and what supply current at 500 Hz?

Comment: Max for 0.1Ω would be 7A, which is why your resistor is getting hot.

Comment: Please clarify whether 250Hz (or 500Hz in the title) are rotational frequencies or the PWM switching frequency.

Comment: Tat is working frequency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing certain important details about your circuit (motor current? motor phase resistance? operating voltage? overall current draw? actual schematic?) any answer to your question is a guess. That being said, your shunt resistor value is atypically high (2 orders of magnitude higher than the one I just designed into a general purpose FOC driver). Double check the motor current, power dissipation in that resistor, and current sense amplifier gain and make sure that's really the value you want.

Comment: Why the resistor is ok at 150Hz and not ok at 500Hz?

Comment: Odds are at 150Hz, there is no overlap between high side and low side being on at the same time.  500Hz faster, so possible overlap.  Ensure you turn high side and low side off separately.

Comment: This answer seems to miss the most likely explanation, "accepting" it without verification was unwise.  Even if one ultimately should shrink the sense resistor, the shoot through problem the heating hints at needs to be corrected first.

Answer (score 0):

Switching loses, the complementary mosfets are on together, you need to increase dead time between the mosfets that drive the coils.
You can do it with R C and a diode to the gates if it can't be done in the chip.

Comment: insufficient dead time won't cause heat to build up in the shunt resistor, it will cause heat to build in the mosfets

Comment: It's the same current through the mosfets and the resistor, when one gets hotter the other one does too.

Comment: It is the same current through the mosfets and the resistor, this is true. I still think you're on the wrong track still because 1.) OP pointed out that the *resistor* was getting hot specifically, but not the mosfets. 2.) Switching losses are not dependent on motor speed; as long as you're getting PWM edges of a consistent frequency the increase in average current draw will be the same. Dead time is to prevent shoot through/partial shoot through; if your shunt resistance is so high that it heats up during normal operation, more dead time won't help you.

Comment: However, it is true that shoot through *could* be a contributing factor. My original comment was misleading; I said that because you can shoot through and heat your mosfets to failure, but still not build a significant amount of heat in a properly rated shunt resistor. I would definitely encourage OP to investigate the possibility of shoot through. It's just not my first guess

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.